# merging excel cells horizontally in python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need to automate an excel task in python. MY input data(excel file) looks like:

```
mid  cola colb colc cold
1 .   yr .  yr . yr  qa
2 .   ch .  ch . ch  bn
3 .   vb .  bg . bg .bc
```

Now I want to merge the columns from cola-cold such that same values are clubbed into single cell.

So my expected output looks like:

```
mid  cola colb colc cold
1 .          yr      qa
2 .          ch .    bn
3 .   vb .   bg      .bc
```

So as depicted above I want the same values across different columns to be clubbed into one. for example 3 yr would be merged into single yr cell dynamically.

I have to do in this python. I tried using openpyexcel but could not proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Adding some reproducible code will be helpful to users looking at your question. pandas is also a useful library for these kinds of problems, you might consider using it.

Comment: I am well aware of pandas. But this is something excel based task to be done in python. So not sure pandas can achieve this. Not able to start, would be glad if someone can give some direction.

Answer (score 0):

From the OpenPyXL [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=Merge)

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws.merge_cells('A2:D2')
ws.unmerge_cells('A2:D2')

# or equivalently
ws.merge_cells(start_row=2, start_column=1, end_row=4, end_column=4)
ws.unmerge_cells(start_row=2, start_column=1, end_row=4, end_column=4)
```

Comment: The range a2:b2 should not be specified a sit keeps on changing. As I mentioned this has to be done dynamically.